# Error running WEB Tomcat application from Intellij IDEA 11 (CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect)

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I moved my project from Win XP to Win 7 Ultimate. It is easy/ standard Java WEB application (Wicket/no DB yet). I use Tomcat 6.0.35 (64 bit) or 6.0.32 (32 bit). The server and my application run properly by starting Tomcat from command line (startup.bat).  Under Intellij Idea it runs good with Debug mode (Shift-F9). But when I am trying to run it with standard mode (Shift-F10) I get error: “Cannot run program "X:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin\catalina.bat" (in directory "X:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin"): CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect.”  And I can’t see compile line. So, I don’t know which parametres incorrect and why?

I was trying to build it by maven and run with Jetty. It works fine also. So, for some reason I can’t run application by using standard fast mode (Shift-F10). Anybody had that problem?

PS: The application was built corrected every trying to run (and was placed in the out directory)

Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

It looks like I found out where was the problem.

A project has dialog “Edit Configuration” (dialog’s title - Run/Debug Configuration). The dialog has 5 tabs. Last right tab (‘Startup/Connection’) provides possibility to describe environment variables to pass it to Java machine. For ‘Debug’ mode by default is set ‘JAVA_OPTS’. But for ‘Run’ mode there is one empty line only (without any values).  Just I put focus and removed that empty line - the problem is gone. It is easy to reproduce. I didn’t add any empty line myself. Possible this is little IDEA bug.

On the other hand I can’t reproduce the problem under Win XP. Possible the reason is – my Win XP has external environment variable ‘JAVA_OPTS’ with memory setting. So, empty line doesn’t add any problems.

Comment: Thank you, that would have taken me forever to figure out.

Comment: Agreed. That would have taken me ages to figure out. Thanks for posting your fix back here.

Comment: THANK YOU. I had swapped back to Eclipse on a large project because I couldn't resolve this. I didn't even notice the empty lines maybe because of the Darcula theme. Fixed my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with IDEA 11.1.5 on Win7 but not on XP. My fix on Win7 was this:  Goto Startup/Connection tab.  On the Pass Environment Variables section I had to delete any blank lines.  These blank lines did not cause a problem for XP, but IDEA on Win7 thought I was passing a bunch of blank parameter assignments and errored out because of it.